# Is there a specific title for wizards?

Tags: single-word-requests, names

I'm writing a fantasy story and I have a wizard in it. His name's Brad, and I'm wondering how a magical figure like him should be addressed. Mr. Brad seems a little lackluster, and Sir Brad wouldn't make sense, since he's not a knight.

To clarify, I'm looking for a title that pertains to wizards that I can put in front of Brad's name, like Sir Brad. Here's an example:

> - "Ah, Mr. Brad, you're looking well today," Bob said.
> - "That's (*wizard term*) Brad to you," he replied tartly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use "Magister" if you like. That was the first word that came to my mind.

Pronounce with the g either hard or soft. The hard pronunciation would be subtler.

Comment: Or ***Magus***.  (Plural magi)

Comment: @Jim yes, but you wouldn't say "Magi Brad", would you? Read the question.

Comment: That is exactly what I am proposing.

Comment: Magister sounds like some kind of lawyer or judge to me. Probably due to *magistrate*.

Comment: @Jim Can't say I agree, but then this is my answer and that's what I would call him. If you think you have a better idea, suggest it as an answer rather than dissing someone else's creative work.

Comment: I wouldn’t call that dissing. I’m not disrespecting you or your answer.  I may be dissenting a bit. But dat and dis are separate disses. :-)